# Symfony Form "POST" -> Retrieve the values ​of a form to enter them in the database

Tags: forms, symfony, post, controller

Good evening everyone,

I allow myself to contact you because I would need help concerning a retrieval of values ​​in a "POST" form in Symfony.

The purpose of this form is: "The user can leave an opinion on the site, by filling out the form"

My problem: I tested in my Controller to perform the "function" which would allow me to retrieve the information sent by the user from the POST form to send them to my database, except that, after several tries, I do not fail to enter information in my database, except "NULL"

Could you help me? Thank you in advance.

My HTML.TWIG "POST" form :

```
<div class="col-md-8 mx-auto" id="formavisall">
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        {% for message in app.flashes('message') %}
                            <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
                                <div class="alert alert-success">
                                    {{ message }}
                                </div> <!-- FIN p-3 my-2 rounded-2 success -->
                            </div> <!-- FIN COL-MD-12 (ID MESSAGECONFIRMATIONUSER) -->
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% for message in app.flashes('error') %}
                            <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    {{ message }}
                                </div> <!-- FIN p-3 my-2 rounded-2 success -->
                            </div> <!-- FIN COL-MD-12 (ID MESSAGECONFIRMATIONUSER) -->
                        {% endfor %}
                        <div class="col-md-12" id="inputradionoteavis">
                            <input type="radio" name="note" id="note" value="1">
                            <label for="note"></label>
                            <input type="radio" name="note" id="note" value="2">
                            <label for="note"></label>
                            <input type="radio" name="note" id="note" value="3">
                            <label for="note"></label>
                            <input type="radio" name="note" id="note" value="4">
                            <label for="note"></label>
                            <input type="radio" name="note" id="note" value="5">
                            <label for="note"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6" id="inputformcontact">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nameavis">Nom :</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" id="nom">
                            </div> <!-- FIN form-group -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6" id="inputformcontact">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="firstnameavis">Prénom :</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prenom" id="prenom">
                            </div> <!-- FIN form-group -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12" id="messageareacontact">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="messageavis">Message :</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                            </div> <!-- FIN form-group -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" name="section" value="content">
                            </div> <!-- FIN form-group -->
                        </div>
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class="row" id="rowbuttoncontact">
                        <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto">
                            <button type="submit" class="form-control" id="buttonformcontact">Laisser un avis</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My "test" function in my Controller :

```
if($request->isMethod('POST')){
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 
            $avis = new Avis();
 
            // On vérifie si les deux mots de passe sont identiques
 
            if($request->request->get('nom') && $request->request->get('prenom') && $request->request->get('message')
                && $request->request->get('note') && $request->request->get('section')){
                $em->persist($avis);
                $em->flush();
                $this->addFlash('message', 'L\'avis a été publié');
 
                return $this->redirectToRoute('accueil');
            }else{
                $this->addFlash('error', 'L\'avis n\'a pas été publié');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to update `$avis` in your controller. You should try adding something in your `if` in order to set the properties:

```
$avis->setNom($request->request()->get('nom'));
$avis->setPrenom($request->request()->get('prenom'));
$avis->setMessage($request->request()->get('message'));
...
```

Also there is a `Form` component in Symfony that can handle all this to save you the trouble: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

Comment: Good evening,

Thank you very much for your help that was it! :-)
It seems more logical now ahah!